# Function overloading not work with namespaces (structures) in c

Tags: c

I have in lib.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LIB {
  int (*a1)(int);
  int (*a2)(int);
} lib;

int a1(int a, int b);
int a2(int a, double b);

#define a0(X, Y) _Generic((X),\
    int:   _Generic((Y),\
        int: a1,\
        double: a2\
    )\
)(X, Y)

lib* getLib(void);
```

In lib.c:

```
#include "lib.h"

int a1(int a, int b) {
 ...
}

int a2(int a, double b) {
 ...
}

lib* getLib(void) {
  lib* ret = (lib*) malloc (sizeof(lib));

  ret->a1 = a1;
  ret->a2 = a2;

  return ret;
}
```

In main.c:

```
#include "lib.h"

int main() {
  lib* l = getLib();
  int v = l->a0(1, 2.4); // error
}
```

Error:

```
error: expected identifier
note: expanded from macro 'a0'
```

Without define, and if a change a0 to a2 it works.
How can I overload function in namespace-structure? Why I have ERROR here?

upd: add "void" (thanks for comments) and I have a mistake in main (first answer) it's just a mistake in question

Comment: This is tangential to what you're asking about, but … Why haven't you defined the prototype for `getLib()` in the header?  What you've provided is a non-prototype declaration — if the function takes no arguments, you need to declare `lib *getLib(void);` because that _is_ a prototype.  And for consistency, you should then define the function as `lib *getLib(void) { … }`.  The function definition as written does not provide a prototype either.

Comment: I'd advise against using `_Generic` in that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A negative answer

Your type `lib` has no member `v`.  The original version of the question contained the code:

```
int l->v = a0(1, 2.4); // error
```

You can't use `int l->v` to create … well, it isn't clear what you expect it to create, but even if there were an element `l->v`, you wouldn't be able to define its type as `int` as you try to.

The problem so far is actually nothing to do with the generic selection operator, `_Generic` (see C11 [§6.5.1.1 Generic selection](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.1.1)).  That's just a red herring that you appear to be chasing.

You could try using:

```
int v = a0(1, 2.4);
```

However, you then run into problems because the result of `a0` is … well, originally I said it was a function pointer, but it's not; the code attempts to call the function.  But you can't select which member of a structure to access via a `_Generic` selection, any more than you can write `l->(a > 1 ? a1 : a2)`.

You are going to need to do some rethinking, I believe.  You seem to be going down the wrong track.  I can't do much more to put you back on track, though, because it is not clear to me where you're trying to go.

Your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268256/function-overloading-not-work-with-namespaces-structures-in-c/66268524?noredirect=1#comment117159742_66268524) mentions C++ namespaces.  If you're emulating namespaces in C, you probably need to use macros and token concatenation.  Overloading functions in C is not trivial.  Trying to use overloads from structure members is mostly not going to work, certainly not using this technique.

As I noted in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268256/function-overloading-not-work-with-namespaces-structures-in-c/66268524?noredirect=1#comment117159767_66268524) response — if you want to use C++ features, use C++.

#### A positive answer

Here is a mechanism which works — but it requires a (slightly) different macro, etc.  I combined your three files into one, but you can easily reseparate the code into three files.  You would remove some, but not all, the `//` comments.

```
// File: lib.h
// #pragma once
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

typedef struct LIB
{
    int (*a1)(int, int);
    int (*a2)(int, double);
} lib;

int a1(int a, int b);
int a2(int a, double b);

#define a0(lib, X, Y) (_Generic((X), \
                          int :   _Generic((Y), \
                                           int : (lib)->a1, \
                                           double : (lib)->a2 \
                                           ) \
                          )(X, Y))

extern lib *getLib(void);

#endif /* LIB_H */

// File: lib.c
// #include "lib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int a1(int a, int b)
{
    return a % b;
}

int a2(int a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

lib *getLib(void)
{
    lib *ret = (lib *)malloc(sizeof(lib));

    ret->a1 = a1;
    ret->a2 = a2;

    return ret;
}

// File: main.c
// #include "lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    lib *l = getLib();
    // int v = l->a0(1, 2.4); // error

    int v = a0(l, 1, 2.4);
    printf("v = %d\n", v);
    int w = a0(l, 24, 5);
    printf("w = %d\n", w);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
v = 3
w = 4
```

Discussion:

The value 'returned' by the generic selection needs to be an element of the `lib` structure.  The function prototypes in the structure are updated to reflect the presence of two arguments, with the second argument being of different types.

The `a0` macro, which hides the generic selection operators, is now invoked with the `lib *`; the actions select different members from the structure, depending on the argument types.  The major difference is that the member access is embedded within the macro, rather than partly inside and partly outside it.

The test code in `main.c` shows that you can get both functions called.  Note that there is no casting involved and that the results are correct (1 + 2 == 3; 24 % 5 == 4)

I'm not suggesting this is a good way to code in C.  It does, however, seem to be feasible to do it like this.

Comment: I just try to make something as namespaces (c++) in c but there are only structures, and I want to make a function overloading here, 
i tried to do just this

Comment: If you want C++ features, use C++.  C is not C++; it is not sensible to try using C as if it is C++.

Comment: the university program is not as fast as the development of С-languages unfortunately, I have to use C

Comment: @THND — note the (major) update under 'A positive answer'.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem you have is that the thing after a `->` token in an expression must be an identifier, the name of a field in the structure.  It can't be an expression that "evaluates" to the name of a field; there's no way to even write such a thing.

a `_Generic` on the other hand is an *expression* -- it can only be used somewhere that C expects an expression,